# Disabled buttons with action in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, button

I want to trigger some action if user clicks on a disabled button in my iOS application, like, `HEY! you gotta pay for that!` or something like that.

I already know how to disable a button, but what I don't know is how to give it an action when the user clicks on it.

Comment: Why do you need that? You can emulate disabled state just with some kind of gray color and still use common handler

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for something like that would be to add some conditions inside the regular action. In addition to that you can in `viewDidLoad` set corresponding UI so it looks like disabled.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP is asking how to setup a button action.

Comment: *disabled button action, which is not touchable. My answer provides work around which will achieve exactly what OP is asking for...

Comment: *"I already know how to make a button dissable, but what i dont know is how to give it a action when the user clicks it."*

Comment: Yeah, but you can't add action for disabled state for button. That's why I provide work around.

Comment: thanks @NickCatib I will check that, i think i will make something like that or just set a alert

Answer (score 0):

You can create a disabled `UIButton` for just the looks. And create a second `UIButton` with the exact same size and location as the first fake one. Make the second button custom with no label and make it `clearColor`.

So the first button is a fake button which looks like a disabled button
The second transparent button on top of the first one has the action linked to it which will fire the `alertView`

Do you think this will work?